# Saving data so it is persistent in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, rest

Over many different Objective-C iOS coding projects I have frequently come across the issue of having data be accessible after I initially got it.

For example, currently I am reading from the stackoverflow API.  I do this with a session and get a dictionary back (my JSON response).

But outside the scope of the session, the dictionary is unavailable! I can't copy the contents to a different dictionary that I've defined globally, or anything.  It's like it disappears outside of the session.

So I am wondering, what's the best way to save this data that I want to use? From what I've been reading it seems like NSUserDefaults or maybe creating a plist file, although admittedly I've been having trouble with both options.  If there is a method that is best for this then I can concentrate on that.

Thank you!

Comment: I would recommend CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how persistent you want to be.

If you save this dictionary into a global variable, it is stored in the part of device's RAM that is reserved for the running app. When the app stops running (gets killed by OS or removed by the user) or if your device reboots - this memory is lost.

If you save this dictionary onto the device's flash memory drive (and its file system) - it will live past restarts/reboots.

Usually people combine the approaches: when you get the data from the network, you keep it in a global variable, and save it to the file system. After the app restart you try to load the data from the file system. The reason for not using the FS all the time is that it is much slower than RAM access. I guess I'm describing [caching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)).

Note that you can implement manual caching (using plain data or text files, `NSUserDefaults`, Core Data or other libraries), but also you can utilize a builtin HTTP cache - `NSURLCache`. If you create a session with `NSURLSession.sharedSession` it will use the default `NSURLCache` and respect a caching policy dictated by the server side.

For more control and full offline support I'd recommend to implement caching manually. See this about [reading and writing plists](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1) and [writeToFile:atomically:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary/1415753-writetofile).